# In SharePoint 2013 List view for duplicate items based on 3 columns

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2013 List view for duplicate items based on 3 columns("date" this can be the date item is added to library)("Name" name of the item)("ID" id number of the item).

Through Grouping in view we can only do with 2 columns in SharePoint. 
But i want duplicate items added on same date,name and id.

I want to know that can this be done through view filter? if so what should be entered in the filter fields?

Comment: Do you mean the internal listitem id or any id of your own?

Comment: it is not internal ID .. Example consider it as "Equipment ID"

Comment: Allright, and the "name", is it the title column or a custom column?

Comment: we got to filter on 3 columns one is equipment ID and EQUIPMENT NAME and Equipment failed Date. All these are custom columns. we need to create view to see duplicate items.

Comment: @user19952                          Example:                                                                                                 21/01/2014     1237   cat                                                                                                                     22/03/2015     3423   rat                                                                                 21/01/2014     1237   cat                                                                       we have to create a view which show the 1st and last items (which are duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a calculated column that combines the 3 field into one that you can use to group by the list items with.

I've created a list of my own with this columns:

- EquipmentId - Number
- EquipmentName - Single line of text
- EquipmentDate - Date and Time
- Calculated - Calculated column

My calculated formula looks like this:

`=TEXT(EquipmentDate;"dd/mm/yyyy")&" - "&EquipmentID&" - "&EquipmentName`

Which give me a column with all 3 fields combined. Now you can use the column `Calculated` to group by and it will sort all duplicates for you.

This is the result in my list.

[image]

Comment: Glad i could help. :) You can change the date formats to anything you want, and you can remove the "-" in between the values if you would like to.

Comment: It shows me error near date format under YYYY with red line. unable to create calculated column because of it

Comment: Equioment date column type is date and time

Comment: What regional settings do you have? English?

Comment: regional setting? Sorry i didnt get you exactly

Comment: What language are you using in sharepoint? Any local language or american/english? Can you create the calculated column or does it say that the formula is wrong? You could try to swap the semicolon ; to a comma ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29038/discussion-between-kats-and-user19952).

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by applying CSS to hide all the "(1)" then this list will show only duplicates